# What tool can I use to create professional and nice charts and tables without any design skill?

Tags: software-recommendation, information-graphics

As I said in the title, I need to find a tool which allows people who don't use any "design software" to create some simple data graphics like bar charts and pie charts that are easy to modify. It can be online or not, free or not, for web or print to be included in PDF documents.

I started to take a look to Google Charts, what do you think about it ?

Thank you very much. It's my first question on this website, I hope i did it well.

Comment: By "design software," are you saying you're ruling out Adobe Illustrator? That would be the best one from a production standpoint.

Comment: Ok. let me more precise about what is the point of this question. I currently use Illustrator in my company to make all kind of charts. The thing is that we want to allow people that don't use illustrator to do it by themselves. I'm looking for a software or a website that can generate simple pies and table that look modern (not excel).

Comment: Close Vote: I don't see this question as being related to Graphic Design. You could try finding the answer on SuperUser. Or you can try editing the question to be about Graphic Design -- perhaps asking how to use Excel to make charts that you don't consider to be `un-modern`.

Comment: @Ryan I do not really see a problem with it. It is a question about how to best represent information, data and objects, and what tools would be best to accomplish this.

Comment: It doesn't really ask about how to best represent information. It alludes to Excel not being modern which I don't agree with and could be an interesting question. Then asks for an alternative that non-designers can drop data into to get the Olitouf's self-perceived definition of modern. Its also a `resource-request/software-rec` question. Tell me in what way is Google Charts more modern then Excel or D3.js or R or OOo Writer or any of the other charting tools on the market?

Comment: In my opinion its no different then saying, "I currently use a Wacom but I want others to be able to do simple illustrations. I'm looking for a mouse that will let them do this." @RandomO'Reilly

Comment: I still do not see the problem. The not-modern bit is a little piece in a comment, no more, and not part of the main question as such. Besides, the "...look modern(not excel)." Does not _necessarily_ mean that excel is not "modern". Comments are often easily misinterpreted. I think it is a perfectly good question. @Ryan

Comment: When i read the description of the website I see that "Graphic Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design." I'm looking for a tool that allow non-designers to realise pies and tables that can be personalised, according to the description of this website bellow, I don't think i'm in the wrong place.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly and Olitouf you're both entitled to your opinion. To me this is too broad. As Lauren and Alan say here -- narrow scope is good. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/278/should-we-allow-recommendation-questions ---- I just don't see anything narrow in this.

Comment: All it really says is, "What do you think about Google Charts?" @Random would you be okay with the question "What do you think about Photoshop?" Probably not. But "Would Adobe Photoshop be the correct tool for X function, x function, and x function in an effort to produce the following result ((image)) or is there a different piece of software I could get the same result with less effort using?" Would start to sound like a reasonable software recommendation question to me.

Comment: Google chart is - compared to Photoshop - a one-trick pony. Google chart basically does one thing and do that well. Not going to continue this discussion; we just seem to interpret it differently.

Comment: I have personally used [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/) in the past. It works well for creating flowcharts and alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LiveGap Charts](http://charts.livegap.com) is good One try it.
it's free and online, no registration needed,no download.Simple with live preview

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's free and online, no registration needed,no download.Simple with live preview

Comment: Actually this tool looks really good, the library is a bit bigger than google graph, there is much more fonts and everything is easy to personalise. In addition, it allows users to export it as HTML. Not bad at all.

Answer (score 4):

As you are saying that excel is not an option, I would go with Google charts. There are other alternatives, but GC seems to me the most flexible:

- It can be stored online in Google Docs, no risk of loosing it when a
  computer crashes
- You use Fusion tables that are incredibly flexible
- It can become formats for web or print
- It can be shared and worked on by multiple people, with revision control
- There are a massive amounts of alternatives and ready-made databases/templates, such as geographic maps (maps are incredibly difficult to maintain in general. Borders etc)
- It is pretty easy to understand
- It is highly customisable, but works fine if one is not interested in the fiddly bits of changing colours etc.
- You can generate multiple charts and maps easily from the same data.

They actually look good with the least amount of effort. And, not the least; they are consistent.

---

**Edit:**

As per your comment I will elaborate a little. When I say "databases" I mean predefined information. If you make a bar chart, Google Charts will take care of choosing colours that works and are not too close in hue as in creating confusion.

As for maps, this is a headache for cartographers and GIS people the world over: borders change, country names changes. To keep reasonably up to date on that is a nightmare. Google charts will also give you countries "weighted" (by this i mean that you apply a number to a country, and GC will adjust colours so as to show "amount" of something.

The gauges, though not very stylish, are all sorted too; the graphics, colours and indication is nothing you have to think about if you do not want to.

All charts are usable out of the box, but you can always change whatever aspect you want should you be so inclined.

Make sure you explore the information in the sidebar, as more charts are "hiding" there. [**Google charts.**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast and so clearly. What do you mean by "There are a massive amounts of alternatives and ready-made databases/templates" ? Are you speaking about template for charts and pie ? where can I find it ? Directly on Google spreadsheet ? Is there a library with all those template ?

Comment: Ah, I will clarify in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://charte.ca - free interactive charts created online in seconds. No designer skills required. And yes, it supports bar and pie charts (there are more than 20 chart types supported).  Some features:

- animations: move the mouse or tap to highlight data items and show callouts
- drill-downs: let your readers navigate to more detailed charts and back
- our charts are standalone SVG files, embed them in your HTML with ease
- it's quick: create a chart, paste data, change appearance, publish in the cloud or export to a file
- integration: use our API to keep your charts up-to-date

Sample editor screenshot:

[image]

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with charte.ca

Comment: That look really nice! Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

> Designed by Travis Kochel, [FF Chartwell](https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-chartwell) is a fantastic typeface for creating simple graphs. Driven by the frustration of creating graphs within design applications and inspired by typefaces such as FF Beowolf and ­­FF PicLig, Travis saw an opportunity to take advantage of OpenType technology to simplify the process.
>
> Using OpenType features, simple strings of numbers are automatically transformed into charts. The visualized data remains editable, allowing for hassle-free updates and styling.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but very interesting thanks :)